# Google Play App Signing fails Game Services login on testing build

Tags: google-api, google-play, keystore, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I curiously enabled **App Signing** in our app, and I found that the problems it created is more than it saved...

First I need to go to Google API to manually change the "Signing-certificate fingerprint" as said in [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8102439/28415848-cf4112d0-6d51-11e7-87e4-603466ebbc36.jpg), and I have to uninstall and install again everytime I want to switch between testing and published build, because the signature is different.

Most annoying thing is, I cannot test Game Services in my testing build! It always failed in authentication. I have to upload it to beta, update from Google Play then so the signature is right and able to login:

```
SignInFailureReason(serviceErrorCode:SIGN_IN_REQUIRED(4),activityResultCode:SIGN_IN_FAILED)
```

I've already added the SHA1 for the upload keystore but it doesn't help...

[image: Google OAuth 2.0 client IDs]

Is there anyway to bypass this?!